# Indexing to get unique fields on 500 million row database mysql

Tags: mysql, indexing, large-data

I have a huge database where most fields are long strings (DNA sequences). Currently it stands at around 500 million rows. For my initial table I just want all 500 million rows that implement into this data structure.

```
Non_unique | Key_name | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Null 

0          | PRIMARY  | 1            | prim_id     | A         | 2654074     | NULL     | NULL   |      
1          | cdr3seq  | 1            | cdr3seq     | A         | 2654074     | NULL     | NULL   | 
1          | cdr3aa   | 1            | cdr3aa      | A         | 2654074     | NULL     | NULL   | 
1          | v_gene   | 1            | vg          | A         | 53081       | NULL     | NULL   | 
1          | d_gene   | 1            | dg          | A         | 46562       | NULL     | NULL   | 
1          | j_gene   | 1            | jg          | A         | 14269       | NULL     | NULL   | 
1          | donor    | 1            | donor       | A         | 1092        | NULL     | NULL   |      
1          | seq_id   | 1            | seq_id      | A         | 2654074     | NULL     | NULL   |      
1          | seq      | 1            | seq         | A         | 2654074     | NULL     | NULL   |
```

They are all B-tree and of the same table (omitted to fit - ignore cardinality  this was taken from the process of uploading). I can easily upload this table with only using the auto_increment primary id (prim_id). But then when I add indexes, it takes forever writing out huge temporary tables. On the other hand, if I design the table first, it takes forever to upload. Is there some sql server option I'm missing? I'm currently running an Innodb engine. Is waiting for indexing something that's inevitable? The reason I have to do this is because all of these columns will eventually be grouped by at some point. For instance I want to create another table from this table thats just unique `seq`, but can't do it without this table first being indexed. Am I going about this the right way?

In addition, for the unique table, I have also tried just to reupload the data file with a unique `seq` index field. This is also taking way too much time.

Thanks so much,

PS, I have a 24-core 64GB server I'm working with for only this data.

Answer (score 0):

With mysql, you can temporarily disable non-unique indexes:

```
ALTER TABLE tbl_name DISABLE KEYS;

-- Do lots of inserts without updating the index every row

ALTER TABLE tbl_name ENABLE KEYS; -- Indexes are refreshed once here
```

To further speed up inserts, wrap your inserts in a transaction, rather than commit for every insert:

```
ALTER TABLE tbl_name DISABLE KEYS;

START TRANSACTION;
-- Do lots of inserts without updating the index or committing every row
COMMIT; -- Inserts are committed in one operation here

ALTER TABLE tbl_name ENABLE KEYS; -- Indexes are refreshed once here
```

Making sure not to load *too* many in each transaction or you'll hit the log high water mark and get an exception and everything will be rolled back (trial and error, but try 10000 at a time).

Comment: wouldn't the enable keys just have to write a bunch of temporary tables since there are unique keys and you would have data modification?

Comment: As per my answer, `DISABLE KEYS` only works for *non* unique indexes. Unique indexes must or course remain active for mysql to be able to maintain uniqueness. Doing this will still be faster than not. However, anyway you look at it, it's going to take a lot of time to do a lot of work

Comment: so for unique keys, whether you group by, upload by, or whatever, its going to take a lot of time